# Short form or a single word for 'Lab Supervisor'

Tags: single-word-requests, abbreviations

Just wondering if there is a Short form or a single word for 'Lab Supervisor'? I need the short form / single word to be at most 8 to 9 letters as the short form / single word will be placed on a menu (which have limited space).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Lab-in-charge* is the shortest I can think of, but overshoots your requirement by a bit.

Comment: Shyam, you give me a hint - probably I can call it as Lab IC?

Comment: @Jack: That should do, I think, given your space constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I used to attend a school where the Lab Supervisor was called "Lab Sup" (pronounced as Lab Soup).

I have come across organisations using "Lab supr" as the unpronounced written short-form. Where "supr" could also stand for "superintendent" - "sch supr" = school superintendent.

Comment: Sounds like the math notation lim sup :-)

Answer (score -1):

*Lab Boss* is a possibility, or *Chief*, or perhaps *Lab [OOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Officer_of_the_Deck)*.